# Need help in factorising a fourth degree polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

$$
a(c^2(a+c)-b^2(a+b))-b(c^2(b+c)-a^2(a+b))+c(b^2(b+c)-a^2(a+c))
$$

On simplification I get,

$$
a^3b-a^3c+ac^3-ab^3-c^3b+cb^3
$$

I am not sure on how to proceed further. Is there any shortcut to factorise this quickly & efficiently?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$=a^3(b-c)-a(b^3-c^3)+bc(b^2-c^2)$$

$$=(b-c)\{a^3-a(b^2+bc+c^2)+bc(b+c)\}$$

Now $a^3-a(b^2+bc+c^2)+bc(b+c)=a(a^2-b^2)-c^2(a-b)-bc(a-b)$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: $$ = a(a + b)(a - b) - c(c(a - b) + b(a - b)) $$

$$ = a(a + b)(a - b) - c(b + c)(a - b) $$

$$ = (a - b)(a(a + b) - c(b + c)) $$

Unsure after this. Please help.

Comment: @Rhaegal, $$a(a+b)-c(b+c)=a^2-c^2+b(a-c)=?$$